# What's the difference between mpimg.imread and plt.imread when I read an image with Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to read an image, and I found that both following sentences are okay, so what's the difference?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = plt.imread("1.jpg")
```

or

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img = mpimg.imread('1.jpg')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off of the [source for matplotlib.pyplot.imread](https://matplotlib.org/stable/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html#imread), it's just an alias for `matplotlib.image.imread`.